# Is it possible to use ASP.NET SignalR on .NET Core( .NET 6 or over)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client

Is it possible to use legacy ASP.NET SignalR [legacy ASP.NET SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) on .NET Core project? I am not asking how to use new version of [ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/SignalR).
We want to upgrade our project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6. And it is using currently using  ASP.NET SignalR. We want to keep ASP.NET SignalR because we cannot update client version of SignalR  for some reason.

Comment: Actually, directly using the legacy ASP.NET SignalR (prior to ASP.NET Core SignalR) in a .NET Core or .NET 6 project is not officially supported. 
ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR have different architectures, and ASP.NET Core was designed to be more modular, cross-platform, and compatible with the .NET Standard.

Comment: But you may have a try few work around ,
Create a separate service or component in your .NET 6 project that acts as a proxy or bridge between the legacy ASP.NET SignalR server and your .NET 6 application. Keep your existing ASP.NET Framework project that uses ASP.NET SignalR as it is. Have these projects communicate with each other using a suitable inter-process communication method, such as APIs, message queues, or shared databases. You can get idea from this [`official document`](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/aspnet-samples/ChatRoom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use legacy ASP.NET SignalR legacy ASP.NET SignalR on
> .NET Core project?

Actually,during the latest release of SignalR there's a lot of improvements so yeah, directly using the legacy ASP.NET SignalR (prior to ASP.NET Core SignalR) in a .NET Core or .NET 6 project is not officially supported. ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR have different architectures, and ASP.NET Core was designed to be more modular, cross-platform, and compatible with the .NET Standard.

So, here's the thing, If you're working on a .NET Core project, it is recommended to use ASP.NET Core SignalR rather than the legacy version. However, if you have specific reasons to use the legacy ASP.NET SignalR in a .NET Core project, you might encounter compatibility issues and limitations.

> We want to keep ASP.NET SignalR because we cannot update client
> version of SignalR for some reason.

Well you can do that, beside please note that using older versions of SignalR along with newer one may have downsides, including missing out on the latest features, security patches, and long-term support.
It's generally recommended to keep your technologies up to date to benefit from improvements and security updates.

Please check the below description carefully:

[image]

**Note:** I would highly recommend you to [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-8.0) before moving further.